# How to update component state in function react js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have two components

- Login Component
- Header Component

I want to display username after login in header.

Below is code...

```
class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props); 

        this.state = {         
          isLoggedIn: false
        };  
      }

    isLoggedIn = () => {    

        var flag = localStorage.getItem('loggedUser') !== null; 
        this.setState({isLoggedIn : flag}); // this line gives error
        return flag;
    }


  render() {

    if(this.isLoggedIn() == true){

    return(
      <div>
           <div className="header">          
              <div className="headerUser">Logged in as: {localStorage.getItem("loggedUser")}</div>
              <img src={Logo} className="app-logo" alt="logo" width="145" height="55" />
           </div>
      </div>
     );

    } else {

    return(
      <div>
           <div className="header">                       
              <img src={Logo} className="app-logo" alt="logo" width="145" height="55" />
           </div>
      </div>
     );

    }

    }
}
export default Header;
```

How to change state inside function as it does not allow me to use this keyword..?

Error :

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Comment: docs? https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

Comment: what's the error you're getting ?

Comment: are you using redux/flex?

Comment: No I am not using

Comment: @dev why are you using a isLoggedIn state as you dont use it anywhere?  I sugget passing it down as prop and render a differrent component if loggedIn prop is  different

Answer (score 1):

Your code has entered a render loop since setState is indirectly called from `render()`. `render()` is called after a `setState` call

Load the required data in `componentDidMount()` and set its value in state and check for the state value in render, and don't use multiple `return` see the below code.

```
class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props); 

        this.state = {         
          isLoggedIn: false
        };  
      }
    componentDidMount() {
       var flag = localStorage.getItem('loggedUser') !== null; 
       this.setState({isLoggedIn : flag}); 
    }    


  render() {

    return(
      { this.state.isLoggedIn ?
        <div>
           <div className="header">          
              <div className="headerUser">Logged in as: {localStorage.getItem("loggedUser")}</div>
              <img src={Logo} className="app-logo" alt="logo" width="145" height="55" />
           </div>
      </div>

    : <div>
           <div className="header">                       
              <img src={Logo} className="app-logo" alt="logo" width="145" height="55" />
           </div>
      </div>

    })
  }
}
 export default Header;
```

`return()` can be further optimized like this

```
 return(

        <div>
           <div className="header">          
              { this.state.isLoggedIn ?<div className="headerUser">Logged in as: {localStorage.getItem("loggedUser")}</div> : null }
              <img src={Logo} className="app-logo" alt="logo" width="145" height="55" />
           </div>
      </div>

)
```

Answer (score 0):

you're calling setState while rendering... try like

```
class Header extends Component {

constructor(props) {

    super(props); 

    this.state = {         
      isLoggedIn: false
    };  
  }

isLoggedIn = () => {    

    var flag = localStorage.getItem('loggedUser') !== null; 
    // this.setState({isLoggedIn : flag}); // delete here 
    return flag;
}


  render() {

if(this.isLoggedIn() == true){

return(
  <div>
       <div className="header">          
          <div className="headerUser">Logged in as: {localStorage.getItem("loggedUser")}</div>
          <img src={Logo} className="app-logo" alt="logo" width="145" height="55" />
       </div>
  </div>
 );

} else {

return(
  <div>
       <div className="header">                       
          <img src={Logo} className="app-logo" alt="logo" width="145" height="55" />
       </div>
  </div>
 );

}

}
}
export default Header;
```

Comment: it does not update state {isLoggedIn} whether user is logged in or not..

Comment: yes. `this.state.isLoggedIn` is unused and completely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You’re setting state in your `isLoggedIn` method,, which triggers another render, which calls `isLoggedIn` again, etc. You should just check the state object in render directly (`this.state.isLoggedIn`), and you should set the state only at the beginning, or when your user’s state changes.

Comment: I want to update state after checking localStorage.getItem('loggedUser')

Comment: That’s fine, but just do that once in the constructor, or in componentWillMount.

Comment: Or check it directly every time you render, and don’t use state to track it.

Answer (score 0):

Well Here is your answer...

```
class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false
        };
    }

    isLoggedIn = () => localStorage.getItem('loggedUser') !== null;

    render() {
        if(this.isLoggedIn()) {
            return(
                <LoggedIn onMount={() => this.setState({isLoggedIn: this.isLoggedIn()})} />
            );
        } else {
            return(
                <div>
                    <div className="header">
                        <img src={Logo} className="app-logo" alt="logo" width="145" height="55" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
export default Header;

class LoggedIn extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.onMount();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="header">
                    <div className="headerUser">Logged in as: {localStorage.getItem("loggedUser")}</div>
                    <img src={Logo} className="app-logo" alt="logo" width="145" height="55"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LoggedIn;
```